# Button doesn't start initially disabled

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, visual-studio, google-chrome

I have a submit button, and want it to start initially disabled, so I did the following the JavaScript;

```
var button = document.getElementById("myBtn");
button.disabled = true;
```

When I run it is still set as enabled for some reason. However, when I have a function that when clicking another button disables the first button it gets disabled;

```
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
}
```

This is the normal declaration of both buttons;

```
<button id="myBtn">Submit</button>
<button onClick = "myFunction()">Disable Submit Button</button>
```

I also tried using the **setAttribute and removeAttribute**

PS: I'm using Visual Studio 2015, and running using Chrome. When I run using internet explorer, it gives me a weird error saying "JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'disabled' of undefined or null reference"[On internet explorer only, in Chrome the button works normally although enabled].

Comment: You must make sure that this JavaScript code either waits for the entire document to load or place it at the bottom of the HTML, so that the button is already loaded by the time the script executes.

Comment: Are you using `DOMContentLoaded` event? when using `button.disabled = true;`

Comment: The disable functionality is working fine if you place it properly. for better understanding please edit your code with header and footer.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thank you, that made it work! never knew that actually affected. I used to place it at the very right top of the HTML.

Comment: @FA Web pages are read left to right, top to bottom, so you can't access something that hasn't been read yet.

Comment: You don't have to move your script down if you use the third method from my answer.

Comment: Did you consider at least upvoting my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function to make it disabled.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
}
myFunction();
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Submit</button>
```

Or use a self-invoking anonymous function:

```js
(function() {
  document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
})();
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Submit</button>
```

Or wait until browser finishes loading the page components:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Submit</button>
```